# How to compare string field as Date in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a string field in a table whose value is date format like: `2020-12-08T18:06:55.132Z` or `2020-12-08T18:06:55.132+11:00`.

How can I search this field based on `date`? Like `select * from my_table where timestamp > '2020-12-08T00:00:00'`.

Comment: Both are valid timestamps with time zone, why do you use a string (text/char/varchar) in the first place?

Comment: because it can be in different date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE to_timestamp(timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MS"Z"') > '2020-12-08T00:00:00'
```

**EDIT:**

Something even easier, which doesn't rely on your timestamp format:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE timestamp::timestamp > '2020-12-08T00:00:00'
```

Comment: I got this error `ERROR:  value for "YYYY" in source string is out of range
DETAIL:  Value must be in the range -2147483648 to 2147483647`.

Comment: I've edited my answer for using "to_timestamp" instead of "to_date". Concerning your error, do you have the entry causing the issue? Because when I try with your example date (by putting `'2020-12-08T18:06:55.132Z'` instead of `timestamp`, it works)

Comment: I've added to my answer another query which doesn't rely on a given format, it may works better.